# using goinstant with node.js in order to use webrtc

Tags: node.js, webrtc, goinstant

i try to implement a collaborative work plateforme based on node.js in back-end that ok
 but i want to integrate webrtc and visoconferance it's possible and how  to use goinstant in BAAS

Comment: Hi @bedoui_mouoifek you can find the code for our WebRTC widget here (https://github.com/goinstant/webrtc) - it's completely open source so you should be able to configure it to your exact requirements.

Comment: thanks for reply ,i have followed the project in order to get videoconferance but by  followning steps it looks like need gortc library (inexist in npm)                                           so i have tried this project 
https://github.com/goinstant/webrtc-demo 
but by  running this project in localhost:3000 it was miss maybe a token property 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined at demo.home
any suggestion please i need it in university project

Answer (score 2):

gortc is published as a component.io component so you won't find it on npm. To build the webrtc widget simply run `npm install` then `grunt build`.

Alternatively, you can install an already built version via bower:

`bower install goinstant-webrtc`

or use a build hosted on GoInstant's CDN:

`https://cdn.goinstant.net/widgets/webrtc/latest/webrtc.min.js`
`https://cdn.goinstant.net/widgets/webrtc/latest/webrtc.css`

For the full `webrtc-demo` you get that error message if redis is not running/found. To start redis do: `redis-server`.